# How to inject datasource in SimpleJDBC

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I have this entry into my application-context.xml

```
<import resource="classpath:spring/v-common-applicationcontext.xml"/>

    <bean id="vltDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.v.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.v.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.v.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.v.password}"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL" />
    </bean>
```

How can I connect to DB using SimpleJdbcCall using Java annotation?
I am new to Spring framework.

Comment: take a look at this one http://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate

Comment: Actually i did already .But in his case ${jdbc.v.username} is hard coded .But in my case this value is present in properties file which is present in another Project.How can i access these values using annotation?

Comment: modiefied my question . I meant SimpleJdbcCall

Comment: Exactly where are you stuck? Do you know how to use annotation-based config at all? What did you try?

Comment: Thanks I resolved the issue.I changed my package name and it worked.I will mark the question as answer